# MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR with IBMXMSDotnetClient 9.3 and .net 6

Tags: .net-core, ibm-mq, tls1.3

I am trying to connect to a remote IBM MQ manager from Windows server using a .net 6 console application and IBMXMSDotnetClient 9.3.4.1.

I am able to connect using the command prompt. The following is what I did:

1. My MQCHLLIB path is C:\MQLib and contains the follow files:

- keyrepo.kdb - contains pkcs12 and CA,
- keyrepo.sth,
- mqclient.ini,
- ccdt.json - contains the channel information etc., cipherSpecification is ANY_TLS13_OR_HIGHER

2. I ran the follow commands from the MQCHLLIB folder to set the variables:

```
set MQCHLLIB=C:\MQLib  
set MQCHLTAB=ccdt.json  
set MQCLNTCF=C:\MQLib\mqclient.ini  
set MQSSLKEYR=C:\MQLib\keyrepo  
set MQCERTLABL=certlabel
```

3. Then I executed:

```
amqsputc queueName *queueManager
```

The connection works and I am able to put a message.

This is a block C# code I've tried for creating the connection. The settings object has properties as outlined above:

```
IConnection connectionWMQ;
IConnectionFactory cf = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ).CreateConnectionFactory();
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CCDTURL, ccdtURL);   /* file://c:\\MQLib\\ccdt.json */
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, "ANY_TLS13_OR_HIGHER");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CLIENT_CERT_LABEL, settings.MQCERTLABL);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, settings.MQSSLKEYR);  //Also tried *USER, got 2393
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_PEER_NAME, settings.MQCERTLABL);

using(connectionWMQ = cf.CreateConnection()){
    //...
}
```

I get the following error

CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode: 2, Reason: 2381.
During execution of the specified method an exception was thrown by another component.
See the linked exception for more information.

at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.Factories.WmqConnectionFactory.CreateProviderConnection(XmsPropertyContext connectionProps)
at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection(String userID, String password)
at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection()

I've also tried

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCERTLABL", settings.MQCERTLABL);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCHLLIB", settings.MQCHLLIB);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCHLTAB", settings.MQCHLTAB);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCLNTCF", settings.MQCLNTCF);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQSSLKEYR", settings.MQSSLKEYR);

Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, HOSTNAME);
properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, PORT);
properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, CHANNEL);
properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, settings.MQSSLKEYR); // Also tried *USER, got 2393 error 
properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, ANY_TLS13_OR_HIGHER);
properties.Add(MQC.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY, settings.MQCERTLABL);
properties.Add("CertificateLabel", settings.MQCERTLABL);
MQQueueManager qManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);
```

[I've looked here for guidance](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=client-cipherspec-support-managed-net)
Been at this for weeks and can't find a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Which dll are you referencing?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm using amqmxmxsstd.dll from the IBMXMSDotnetClient nuget package

Comment: You must use *USER or *SYSTEM,  this means you need to put the certs in the windows key store.

Comment: amqmxmxsstd.dll will only run on managed mode.   To use kdb files you need to run in unmanaged mode.   amqsputcis not a .net app, it uses kdb files.

Comment: The certs are in the window key store. I changed the code to set the XMSC.WMQ_SSL_PEER_NAME to the DN of the cert and XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY to *USER. I get   MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR

Comment: Are they in the machine key store or the user's key store?   XMSC.WMQ_SSL_PEER_NAME is not a setting related to your app cert,  you would use that to validate the DN of the queue manger you are connecting to,  I would suggest setting that later after you get a successful connection.   You would want the CertificateLabel setting to match the windows key store friendly name.

Comment: They are in the user's key store.

Comment: Have you checked the of the friendly name match the cert label you are specifying?

Comment: Yes. The friendly name is ibmwebspheremquserid

Comment: I would suggest you run a .net trace then,  it may show you the problem if not open a case with IBM.

Comment: Back to this. I'm getting this error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090331): The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.